# Can a Google Form be auto filled and submitted, using data from a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to determine how to get a script to take data from a spreadsheet and fill out a form, then submit the form.  The script would be part of the spreadsheet

**FORM**

My Form has 3 text fields, one date, and one choose from a list field.
User Name:       "TEXT"
User's Manager:  "TEXT"
Start Date:      "DATE"
Location:        "LIST"
Cube#:           "TEXT"

**SPREADSHEET**

The spreadsheet has rows listing a variety of users, only some of which would need to have this form submitted.
The spreadsheet has a column relating to each of the form fields plus an additional column to indicate that the form should (or should not) be submitted for this user.

I would also need the script to datestamp the cell that indicates the form should be submitted after the form has been completed.

I've seen several posts about populating forms, but they all seem to be in the creation of the form, not the population of an existing form.

I'm exceptionally new to scripting, so any help is much appreciated.  Please let me know if I need to supply additional information.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you the have answer now? same concern also.

Answer (score 3):

This question was about simulating form submissions: [Use App Scripts to open form and make a selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410497/use-app-scripts-to-open-form-and-make-a-selection/20510224#20510224).

There are numerous examples of [creating timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20timestamp).

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10966733/1677912) of a menu function that determines the currently selected row.

By adapting from those, you should be able to write a function that gathers the data from the currently active row, checks whether submission is warranted, and if so simulates a form submission of that data, then appends a timestamp to record when the action was taken.